# Error when returning single json object after an ajax call in django

Tags: ajax, json, django

when i get multiple objects, it works fine but if i only get 1, it returns an error

views.py

```
def get_incident_personnel(request):
    args = {}
    store = Store.objects.get(store_id=request.POST['store'])
    data = serializers.serialize('json', store)
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/json')
```

and here is my ajax.js

```
$('#id_store').change(function() {
    var store = $('#id_store').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/incidents/get_incident_personnel/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'store': store,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

        },
        success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Where do you get the error, server or client side ? What's the error ?

Comment: i get POST http://localhost:8000/incidents/get_incident_personnel/ 500     (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR) on client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `serializers.serialize` on a model instance, only on a QuerySet. Use `filter` even though you know you're only going to get one object.

```
store = Store.objects.filter(...)
```